# Assert cannot be resolved

Tags: java

**Description**:"Assert cannot be resolved"
**Resource** :ConsumerAccountProfileAssertion.java 
**Path** : /SCACCWSTest/src/test/java/ford/cucumber/cap/assertion 
**Location** : line 81 
**Type** :Java Problem Assert cannot be resolved 
 Eclipse OxygenWas

```
for(String outputFieldToBeVerified : outputFieldsToBeVerified) {
            switch (CommonUtils.trimAndConvertToUpperCase(outputFieldToBeVerified)) {
                case CommonConstants.OUTPUT_FIELD_CONSUMER_ID:
                    consumerBOFromDB = ConsumerAccountProfileDAO.getPartialName(consumerID);
                    Assert.assertTrue(consumerID!=null && consumerID.equals(consumerBOFromDB.getConsumerID()));
                    //10002224452,10007356852,"10013131152",consumerBOFromDB
                break;
```

Comment: `Assert` comes from jUnit. Make sure `jUnit` is in classpath in testscope.

Comment: So, you don't know what I meant. You should read more about classpath. Check Will's answer below.

Comment: In the Java Build Path, I have added one more library JUnit5 <br>
Right Click on the module, Build Path > Configure Build Path > Java Build Path > Add Library > JUnit (Next) > JUnit 5 > Finish. <br> This solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to use [JUnit](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue(boolean)), you'll need to `import org.junit.Assert;` and make sure you have JUnit in your [classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) (see [here](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fref-preferences-build-path.htm) for Eclipse Oxygen release). Or whatever assertion library.

Comment: In the Java Build Path, I have added one more library JUnit5


Right Click on the module, Build Path > Configure Build Path > Java Build Path > Add Library > JUnit (Next) > JUnit 5 > Finish.

This solves my problem

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse, importing the below package will resolve the issue(jUnit 5)

```
import org.junit.Assert;
```

Answer (score 0):

put your test code in the test folder (src/main/test/) not (src/main/java)

Comment: Please explainthe effect of that and why it solves the problem.