# Assert can't resolved error on Eclipse Oxygen+Open JDK 11

Tags: eclipse, junit, assert, java-11

Subject : Assert can't be resolved

Recently I have removed Java and added OpenJDK 11 and Eclipse Oxygen ,due to these changes I am getting the error "Assert can't be resolved " in my java project . Error will be gone if I add Junit library manually but this will  lead to change in .classpath as I am using Maven.

JUnit 4.12 dependency has already been added to pom.xml,still I am facing this error.Is there any way to resolve this..?

Reference link : [Assert cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708455/assert-cannot-be-resolved/54308789#54308789)

The above question is similar to mine but it couldn't solve my issue..

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Oxygen doesn't support Java 11 (It might be able to be run with it, but it cannot understand the .class files provided by it)

The first Eclipse version that supports Java 11 is Eclipse 2018-12, downloadable from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Also, make sure your eclipse build settings are in sync with the `pom.xml`
(Right-click on the project and choose `Maven` > `Update Project`)

Comment: Yeah I am using **eclipse-java-2018-12-R-win32-x86_64**  Still I am facing the said issue.. Even I did "Maven > Update Project" many times, nothing resolved my issue..

Comment: Just to be sure: Compilation from the command line does work? And you haven't added a module-info.java?